# get an output from terminal and write it in a file, FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory error found in python

Tags: python, terminal, bioinformatics, fasta

I have a list called proteins which keeps the names of a group of proteins. For each protein of this list I want to get the id and the amino acid sequence from a ".faa" extension file. The output should be saved in a new file. To get the id and the amino acid sequence for each protein and how I store them, I have written this piece of code :

```
import re
import sys 
import cmd 
import readline
import os
from os import path
import numpy as np
import subprocess
import tempfile
from Bio import SeqIO
def createCluster (filename) :
    noLine = 0
    inputfile = './%s'%filename
    with open(inputfile,'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            noCol = 0
            noLine +=1
            cmd1 = '> clust_%s_BREX_A.faa' %noLine
            os.system(cmd1)
            noCol = len(line.split())
            if noCol >= 2 :
                #print(noCol)
                proteins = line.split()
                #print(proteins)
                for p in proteins:
                    cmd2 = "grep -A1 -w '%s' BrxA_BREX_Sys_Proteins_Singleline.faa "%(p.strip())
                    os.system(cmd2)
                    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd2, stdout=subprocess.PIPE ).communicate()[0]
                    with open ('clust_%s_BREX_A.faa' %noLine, 'w') as f:
                        SeqIO.write(proc, f, 'fasta')

            else:
                break
if __name__=="__main__" :
    if len(sys.argv) !=2:
        print('Usage: python3 createClusters.py <filename>')
        sys.exit()
    file_name = sys.argv[1]
    print("Reading from file '%s'."%file_name)
    createCluster(file_name)
```

First I output the information in the terminal using :

```
cmd2 = "grep -A1 -w '%s' BrxA_BREX_Sys_Proteins_Singleline.faa "%(p.strip())
os.system(cmd2)
```

"BrxA_BREX_Sys_Proteins_Singleline.faa " is a fasta file containing many protein ids and amino acid sequences.
Then I want to take this output and store it in a new file. I do this like :

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd2, stdout=subprocess.PIPE ).communicate()[0]
with open ('clust_%s_BREX_A.faa' %noLine, 'w') as f:
    SeqIO.write(proc, f, 'fasta')
```

I get an error like this :

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "grep -A1 -w 'AAL23316.1' BrxA_BREX_Sys_Proteins_Singleline.faa ": "grep -A1 -w 'AAL23316.1' BrxA_BREX_Sys_Proteins_Singleline.faa "
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), the first argument of `Popen`, `args`, should be a list of command line elements, or single string that is the program to execute, without arguments:

> On POSIX, if args is a string, the string is interpreted as the name or path of the program to execute. However, this can only be done if not passing arguments to the program.

Try splitting your command line into elements, as follows:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd2.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE ).communicate()[0]
```

Or, likely more robust:

```
import shlex
proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd2), stdout=subprocess.PIPE ).communicate()[0]
```

Answer (score -1):

Well I think the answer is pretty obvious. You need to remove the first part that is  `grep -A1..`. You are trying to open a command in a shell. Which is kinda not a valid file.
You need to put out the `grep -A1 -w '%s'`  part of the string out if you are trying to open a file.

Comment: remove it from where? Remove it compitely or from  proc? I need this part to be executed in my terminal, ater I get the output in the terminal I want to extract it and store it in a file.

Comment: Yes I get it, but it seems you are trying to open a command line. Which does not work. You either execute the command that opens the file, or you just open the file. You cannot do both I think

Comment: can you pleasee maybe copy and paste my code and discard what you think  I should discard..? somehow I am not understanding you :/